# R-project data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using a function that should return a data frame (table?) with 2 columns.

here is the function:

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {

    csvfiles <- sprintf("/Users/myname/Desktop/%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)

    nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))
    data.frame(ID=sprintf('%03d', id), countrows=sapply(csvfiles,function(x) length(count.fields(x))))
    }
```

Sample output:

```
                                       ID countrows
/Users/myname/Desktop/specdata/100.csv 100      1097
/Users/myname/Desktop/specdata/101.csv 101       731
```

I need the output to show just the number in that file path. So the first one should read just 100, the second record 101 etc.

This does the job in the console

```
colID <- sprintf('%03d', id)
```

But I'm trying to integrate it into my function with no joy.

I have tried:

```
nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))
+ data.frame(ID=sprintf('%03d', id), countrows=sapply(csvfiles,function(x) length(count.fields(x))))
```

and I have tried:

```
 complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {

    csvfiles <- sprintf("/Users/myname/Desktop/%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)

    colID <- sprintf('%03d', id)

    nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))
    data.frame(ColID, countrows=sapply(csvfiles,function(x) length(count.fields(x))))
    }
```

I'm sure I'm just a step away?

BASED ON FEEDBACK BELOW

I tried this

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {

    csvfiles <- sprintf("/Users/myname/Desktop/%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)

    colID <- sprintf('%03d', id)

    nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))
    data.frame(ID=id, countrows=sapply(csvfiles,function(x) length(count.fields(x))))

    row.names(colID) <- basename(row.names(colID))
    }
```

That's giving back an error:
"Error in basename(row.names(colID)) : 
  a character vector argument expected
"

Comment: Perhaps `row.names(x) <- basename(row.names(x))`

Comment: Romain thanks again for your help with my learning R. I cannot see where I would integrate your line of code? Would it go into the existing row starting "nrows..." or would it be a stand alone line? Is basename a function in itself?

Comment: I meant, store your data frame in a variable, and assign row names to it. Coming up yourself with how to do this is goof enough learning exercize :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it one of two ways:
A (inside the function):

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {

   csvfiles <- sprintf("/Users/myname/Desktop/%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)

   nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))
   data.frame(ID=sprintf('%03d', id), 
              countrows=sapply(csvfiles,function(x) length(count.fields(x))),
             row.names=id
           )
       }
```

B (outside the function):

```
 compdf <- complete()
row.names(compdf) <- 1:NROW(compdf)
```